# Fire DoubleClick event on ListView in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Is it possible to fire a `DoubleClick` event on a `ListView` programmatically? Without needing to know the location/signature of the event handler?

Comment: why you need to do that?

Comment: Why didn't you call directly the method instead ? I'm not sure to see in which case it could be a good think, or a real need, to do so.

Comment: Sounds like an awfully indirect way to execute logic. Why not directly call whatever happens when the listview is clicked?

Comment: Do you want to simulate a double-click in an application for which you don't have source code?

Comment: @Marco : you're getting close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I blogged about that a while ago: [Simulate a Click](http://esskar.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/simulate-a-click/); it is not a real click, but it triggers the event handlers. The blog say "OnClick", replace it with "OnDoubleClick" and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

if I understood what you want instead doing so:

```
private void MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //some code on mouse double click
}
```

make:

```
private void MethodToExecuteOnDoubleClick()
{
  //some code on mouse double click
}

private void MouseDoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MethodToExecuteOnDoubleClick();
}
```

and then you can call MethodToExecuteOnDoubleClick() whenever you want without need to rise doubleclick event

Answer (score 1):

For simulate mouse click you can do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

  //....

   [DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;


   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      //Call the imported function with the cursor's current position
      int X = Cursor.Position.X;
      int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }

   //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to create an encapsulating control and to handle any logic that you might need in there.